# Css: Placing an image immediately to the right of a title and subtitle

Tags: css, positioning

Suppose I have this html code:

```
<img src="pic.jpg"/>
<h1>Title!</h1>
<h5>A subtext</h5>
<hr/>
```

What css code would give me the following result?

[image: css_example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="container">

<div class="content_left">
  <h1>Title!</h1>
  <h5>A subtext</h5>
  <hr/>
</div>
<div class="content_right">
  <img src="pic.jpg"/>
</div>
<div>
```

css:

```
#container {
  width: yourwidth;
  height: yourheight;
}

.content_right {
  float:right;
  width: width of image;
}
.content_left {
  float:left;
  width: width of text;
}
```

This is of course only one of alot of ways this can be done...